# Time distributed layer keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Iam trying to understand the time distributed layer in keras/tensorflow.
As far as I have understood it is a kind of wrapper, making it possible to in example process a sequence of images.

Now Iam wondering how would design a time distributed network without using the time distributed  layer.

In example if I would have a sequence of 3 images, each having 1 channel and a pixel dimension of 256x256px, that should first be processed by a CNN and then by LSTM cells.
My input to the time distributed layer would then be (N,3,256,256,1), where N is the batch size.

The CNN would then have 3 outputs, which are fed to the LSTM cell.

Now, without using the time distributed layers, would it be possible to accomplish the same by setting up a network with 3 different inputs and 3 similar CNNs? The outputs of the 3 CNNs  could then be flattened and concatenated.

Is that any different from the time distributed approach?

Thanks in advance,

M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a prototype for you. I used the least number of layers and arbitrary units/kernels/filters, change them as you like. It creates a cnn model first that takes inputs of size (256,256,1). It uses the same cnn model 3 times (for your three images in the sequence) to extract features. It stacks all the features using Lambda layer to put it back in a sequence. The sequence then goes through LSTM layer. I have chosen for the LSTM to return a single feature vector per example, but if you want the output to be a sequence as well, you could change it to say `return_sequences=True`. You could also add final additional layers to adapt it to your needs.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Conv2D, Flatten, Lambda
from tensorflow.keras import Model
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K

def create_cnn_model():
  inp = Input(shape=(256,256,1))
  x = Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=5, strides=2)(inp)
  x = Flatten()(x)
  model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=x, name='cnn_Model')
  return model


def combined_model():
  cnn_model = create_cnn_model()
  inp_1 = Input(shape=(256,256,1))
  inp_2 = Input(shape=(256,256,1))
  inp_3 = Input(shape=(256,256,1))

  out_1 = cnn_model(inp_1)
  out_2 = cnn_model(inp_2)
  out_3 = cnn_model(inp_3)

  lstm_inp = [out_1, out_2, out_3]
  lstm_inp = Lambda(lambda x: K.stack(x, axis=-2))(lstm_inp)
  x = LSTM(units=32, return_sequences=False)(lstm_inp)

  model = Model(inputs=[inp_1, inp_2, inp_3], outputs=x)
  return model
```

Now create the model as such:

```
model = combined_model()
```

Check the summary:

```
model.summary()
```

which will print:

```
Model: "model_14"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_53 (InputLayer)           [(None, 256, 256, 1) 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_54 (InputLayer)           [(None, 256, 256, 1) 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_55 (InputLayer)           [(None, 256, 256, 1) 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
cnn_Model (Model)               (None, 254016)       416         input_53[0][0]                   
                                                                 input_54[0][0]                   
                                                                 input_55[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_3 (Lambda)               (None, 3, 254016)    0           cnn_Model[1][0]                  
                                                                 cnn_Model[2][0]                  
                                                                 cnn_Model[3][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_13 (LSTM)                  (None, 32)           32518272    lambda_3[0][0]                   
==================================================================================================
Total params: 32,518,688
Trainable params: 32,518,688
Non-trainable params: 0
```

The inner cnn model summary could be printed:

```
model.get_layer('cnn_Model').summary()
```

which currently prints:

```
Model: "cnn_Model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_52 (InputLayer)        [(None, 256, 256, 1)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_10 (Conv2D)           (None, 126, 126, 16)      416       
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_6 (Flatten)          (None, 254016)            0         
=================================================================
Total params: 416
Trainable params: 416
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________
```

Your model expects a list as input. The list should have a length of `3` (since there are 3 images in a sequence). Each element of the list should be a numpy array of shape (batch_size, 256, 256, 1). I have worked a dummy example below with a batch size of 1:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((256,256,1)) # first image filled with zeros
b = np.zeros((256,256,1)) # second image filled with zeros
c = np.zeros((256,256,1)) # third image filled with zeros

a = np.expand_dims(a, 0) # adding batch dimension to make it (1, 256, 256, 1)
b = np.expand_dims(b, 0) # same here
c = np.expand_dims(c, 0) # same here


model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
# train your model with model.fit(....)

e = model.predict([a,b,c]) # a,b and c have shape of (1, 256, 256, 1) where the first 1 is the batch size
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for this great and detailed example! 
So in your model you use three inputs and three times the same CNN model. The outputs are then stacked together and fed into the LSTM layer. Is that basically what the time distributed layer in keras does?

Comment: Hi, yes. That's my understanding. The official documentation in keras says the same: 
 https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/

Comment: Hi again! Great, thanks for the clarification :-) Cheers,M